# How do I determine if the database connection is PostgreSQL or MySQL or MSSQL?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm developing an internal business intelligence application that has connections to multiple databases which the user can dynamically define. I need to know what kind of database a connection object is using. How would I do this in python.

Comment: Hello, what have you tried ? What python library are you using to connect to the databases ? Generally you need to know the database type to connect so your question seems a bit backwards.

Comment: Your Python code defines the datasource connection. Search your codebase for the strings "postgres", "mysql", and "mssql".

Comment: This is too broad; Pyramid applications can use any number of database libraries. If you already made specific choices about how your app connects to databases, then please share them.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/#getting-started) to go with python.

This supports a `bind` feature that allows you to create multiple binds with different databases. 
Eg.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://localhost/main'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'users':        'mysqldb://localhost/users',
    'appmeta':      'sqlite:////path/to/appmeta.db'
}
```

And if after making the connections/sessions you need info then doing

`session.bind.dialect.name`

will return the name of the database from the urls added above.

A good gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/lmyyao/37157fff3ba90889d7c1e0f9dc774253).